# jQuery UI Datepicker - How to dynamically disable specific dates

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, datepicker, asp.net-web-api2

I am using jQuery UI Datepicker widget in one of my projects.
I want to disable an array of specific dates in datepicker calendar, but I want to be done after ajax call is made, not on page loading.

My html element related to datepicker is:

```
<input type="text" id="inpIdForDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Choose for date" />
```

jQuery code which loads datepicker widget to html element is:

```
$("#inpIdForDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        firstDay: 1
    });
```

Now, I want to start an ajax call to retrieve an array of dates to be disabled in datepicker calendar.

```
$.ajax({
        method: "get",
        url: "../api/...",
        success: function (arrayOfDatesToBeDisabled) {
            $("#inpIdForDate").datepicker({
                beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                    var string = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
                    return [arrayOfDatesToBeDisabled.indexOf(string) == -1]
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The code above does not give any error but it does NOT disable dates from arrayOfDatesToBeDisabled.
Any suggestion how to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

you can wait for the response:

```
async function datesToDisable(){
   let dates = await $.ajax(method: "get", url: "../api/...");
   return dates
}

$(function(){
    $('something').datepicker({
         beforeShowDay: datesToDisable
     });
})
```

Comment: What is 'res' in async function datesToDisable()?

Comment: @szti1516 sorry, i meant `dates`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the string after convert is the same type with string in arrayOfDatesToBeDisabled? Cause 'yy-mm-dd' in Jquery datepicker means 'yyyy-mm-dd'.

Comment: I am sure. Strings from arrayOfDatesToBeDisabled are in format 'yyyy-mm-dd', for example: [ '2020-09-01', '2020-09-03', '2020-09-10' ].

Comment: it seems the beforeShowDay only works when you first initialize. therefore use await to wait for ajax output before initializing datepicker. or put all initializing datepicker inside ajax's response.

Comment: @Viet use of async function and await to wait for ajax output does not work, but initializing datepicker inside ajax's success method does fine.

Comment: In theory, using async-await is equivalent to executing function in ajax's response if async-await is working properly. If async-await is not working as expected, open another post :D